# Trouble with VLAN on my L2/L3 switch and pfsense

Tags: networking, vlan, pfsense

I'm attempting to use my TPLink JetStream 16-Port Gigabit L2 Managed Switch to setup a VLAN for my home devices network, so I can keep them segregated from my server network.

These devices are on both wireless and wired, including my Echo Dot which is wireless, EcoBee (wireless) and my Phillips Hue which is wired.

When I connect my home automation devices to my Wireless they are connecting to a hidden -Home network with a VLAN ID of 20.

Here's roughly what the setup of this segment of my network looks like:
[image: network diagram]

As you can see I have a couple other VLAN's, 10 for Guest network and 0 for all other wireless devices.

I've gotten my home automation wireless devices to connect successfully by doing the following on VLAN20 on the switch:

Port 2 and 16 are tagged, 15 is untagged.

VLAN10 just has ports 1 and 2 tagged.

VLAN0 has 2 tagged, and all other ports untagged except 15 and 16.

Everything seems to work except the Phillips Hue Bridge is not connected at all. From what I can tell its connection stops at the switch.

I've played around with what I envision to be every combination of tagged and untagged VLAN combinations without much luck.

Thanks for any guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Given every vlan has its own subnet and the pfsense forbids traffic between subnets, you would have to tag port 15 with vlan id 20.

Have you tested, that the vlans are seperated and not bridged at your pfsense? This might explain, why things seem to be working, although not as expected.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I just tagged port 15 with VLAN20, rebooted the hue and switch and no change. Definitely no bridges setup on the pfSense.

Comment: Ok. Two last tries: 1. Additionally to my answer untag vlan id 0 on port 15. 2.: Tag port 16 with vlan ids 0,10,20. Tag port 15 with id 20 and tag port 2 with ids 0,10,20.

Comment: No good there either bud. I'll reconvene what I've got now in my original question and see if we can get a fresh set of eyes on this. Thanks for your help.